# Google App Engine - Dealing with concurrency issues of storing an object

Tags: google-app-engine, concurrency, google-cloud-datastore

My `User` object that I want to create and store in the datastore has an `email`, and a `username`.  How do I make sure when creating my `User` object that another `User` object doesn't also have either the same `email` or the same `username`?

If I just do a query to see if any other users have already used the username or the email, then there could be a race condition.

UPDATE:
The solution I'm currently considering is to use the MemCache to implement a locking mechanism.  I would acquire 2 locks before trying to store the `User` object in the datastore. First a lock that locks based on `email`, then another that locks based on `username`.

Since creating new `User` objects only happens at user registration time, and it's even rarer that two people try to use either the same username or the same email, I think it's okay to take the performance hit of locking.

I'm thinking of using the MemCache locking code that is here: http://appengine-cookbook.appspot.com/recipe/mutex-using-memcache-api/

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try storing your User with their email as the `key_name`.  This can be done in one simple step:

```
MyUser.get_or_insert(email)
```

Getting your `MyUser` by an email is also easy:

```
MyUser.get_by_key_name(email)
```

See this similar question: [add properties to users google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504748/add-properties-to-users-google-app-engine)

So that solves the problem of two users with the same email.  To do the same for usernames, perform the "get users with this username" query and the "insert a user with this username" in a [transaction](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions.html) (this is what `get_or_insert()` does behind the scenes).

You can catch a `TransactionFailedError` to find cases when another user "takes" that username during your transaction.

You *definitely* don't want to use a memcache mutex, since that `while` loop waiting for the lock to free up can spend a lot of your memcache API call quota.

Comment: Are you sure I can perform the "get users with this username" query and "insert a user with this username" in the same transaction?  You can only operate on one entity group per transaction.  And to do a query you have to have an ancestor filter on it.    http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions.html#What_Can_Be_Done_In_a_Transaction

Comment: You can query for MyUsers and insert a MyUser in a transaction, you just can't query for OtherThings and insert a MyUser in a transaction.  What may be sticky is, I don't know if you can do `get_or_insert()` inside a transaction, since it itself is a transaction.  In this case you'll need to query for username _and_ email availability before inserting a MyUser.

Comment: What would the ancestor filter that I put for the query be?  None of my `User` objects have a common ancestor.  And it would be bad to make  all of my `User` objects have a common ancestor, thus making them be in the same entity group.

Comment: Spines is right: You cannot do a query in a transaction unless it has an ancestor filter, and none applies here.

Comment: So there's just no way to do this in a transaction?  What's the best way to make sure two users don't end up with the same email or username?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the JPA impl of datastore, you just have to set the annotation

@Column(unique=true)
Field field

This way the db will reject your insert/update.. i guess it's implemented by gdatastore, it's not a big matter for me to give a "technical error" to the user on such a specific case... but anyway you could catch a constraintviolation exception. I guess JDO also have this.

But actually i don't even know if you'r using Python or Java...

In Java as far as i know you can do a select request in a transaction...

About transactions you should also check what is transaction isolation and how it works on GAE...